# Twitter web intent URL encoding not working

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to encode my URL with javascript. But the URL never gets put into the tweet. I think it has something to do with some parameters in my URL having spaces.

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=40%25%20Off%20Prom%20Tuxedo%20Rental&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3A5757%2Fcoupon%3Fref_name%3DTest%20Name%26school%3DTest%20School

If I take out the `%20`'s from my URL then it works...

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=40%25%20Off%20Prom%20Tuxedo%20Rental&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3A5757%2Fcoupon%3Fref_name%3DTestName%26school%3DTestSchool

But I need to keep those spaces in there.

This is the javascript code I have right now...

```
var text =  encodeURIComponent("40% Off Prom Tuxedo Rental");
var couponURL = encodeURIComponent("http://example.com/coupon/?ref_name=Test Name&school=Test School");
var twitterURL = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=";
var twitterURL = twitterURL+text+"&url="+couponURL;
```

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any fixes till now ?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, a percentage sign equals %25, so if you want to include the spaces in your tweet link, use %2520 instead of %20. So wherever you were going to use %20, use %2520 instead.

```
var text =  "40% Off Prom Tuxedo Rental";
text = text.replace(/\s/g, "%2520")
```

Comment: Thank you!! You saved my sanity. It was driving me crazy. This worked perfectly.